# how to properly save table rows values in django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I have two django models for orders and order items.I loop through each table row in jquery and pass the results to the View  via ajax.The problem is that for each ajax call that gets fired it creates a database record for the orders.I want to create an order and respective order items from the table rows.What am i doing wrong.Thanks

//The View

```
class ProductListView(TemplateView):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.is_ajax():
            line_items = {}
            product_id = request.POST.get("product_id")
            price = request.POST.get("price")
            quantity = request.POST.get("quantity")
            subtotal = request.POST.get("subtotal")
            grandtotal = request.POST.get("grandtotal")
            products = CustomerPrice.objects.get(id=product_id)
            product_name = products.product

            line_items = {
              "product_id":product_name,
              "price":price,
              "quantity":quantity,
              "subtotal":subtotal,
              "grandtotal":grandtotal,
            }


        Order.objects.place('Credit Card','Pending',
                grandtotal,subtotal,125,line_items,request.user)
       return super(ProductListView,self).get(request)
```

//The Model Manager

```
class OrderManager(models.Manager):
    def place(self,payment_method,payment_status,
              grandtotal,sub_total,po_number,lineitems,username):

        charge_amount = float(lineitems['grandtotal'])
        order = self.create(customer=username,
                            sub_total=lineitems['subtotal'],
                            total = lineitems['grandtotal'],
                            charge_amount=charge_amount,
                            #payment_method=payment_method,
                            payment_status=payment_status,
                            order_number=po_number)
                            #billing_address=billing_address,
                            #updated_by=username,
                            #created_by=username)

        OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,
                                 product=lineitems['product_id'],
                                 price=lineitems['price'],
                                 quantity=lineitems['quantity'],
                                 sub_total=lineitems['subtotal'],
                                 total =lineitems['subtotal'],
                                 #tax_rate=tax_rate,
                                 #tax_method=tax_method,
                                 updated_by=username,
                                 created_by=username)

        return order
```

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an idea of how this should be implemented. Make a single ajax post request with payload.

`{customer: "",
 payment_method: ""
 ... 
 line_items: [
  {
   product_id: '101',
   quantity: '2',
   ...
  },
  {
   product_id: '102',
   quantity: '1',
   ...
  }]
}`

Now in the django view, Create an `Order` object with `customer`, `payment_method` details etc, and loop through each line item and create a corresponding `OrderLineItem` object.

Comment: Thanks Rag Sagar let me try